# how do calculate age if date stored in array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to calculate age of students and i have stored their values days, month and year in array like below:

```
$day = array(30, 03);
$month = array(07, 12);
$year = array(1998, 1997);
```

I want to calculate their current age and below result. so, how can i calculate their age within array.

```
$age = array(18, 19);
```

Comment: both the ages should be 18 if you are considering month and days too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and return difference using [`DateTime::diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) inside closure.

```
$day = array(30, 03);
$month = array(07, 12);
$year = array(1998, 1997);
$now = new DateTime();

$age = array_map(function($year, $month, $date) use ($now) {
    return (new DateTime($year . '-' . $month . '-' . $date))->diff($now)->y;
}, $year, $month, $day);
```

Comment: This is great example of how to use `array_map`. I would just recommend to put `new DateTime()` outside of callback and pass it to the anonymous `function` using `use` statement - just for performance sake.

Comment: @ofca I thought of it while writing, and skipped as I was also trying to make it short.

Comment: @kamalpal error showing - array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array

Comment: @SantoshKhatri the parameters you are passing after closure, make sure all of them are array. see it working: https://eval.in/668551

Comment: Perfect answer and nice use of array_map

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that all three array will have same count:

```
$age=[];

for($i=0;$i<count($day);$i++)
{
$date= $day[$i]."-".$month[$i]."-".$year[$i];
$from = new DateTime($date);
$to   = new DateTime('today');
$diff = $from->diff($to)->y;
array_push($age,$diff);
}
print_r($age);
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but what will be logic to count age. can you share me complete function.

Answer (score 0):

Demo: https://eval.in/668554

Solution:

```
$day = array(30, 03, 23);
$month = array(07, 12, 03);
$year = array(1998, 1997, 1987);
$age = [];

$now = new DateTime('today');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($day); $i++) {
    $d = $day[$i];
    $m = $month[$i];
    $y = $year[$i];

    // Create DateTime object
    $birthdate = new DateTime($y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d);
    // Calculate difference between birthdate and now and get years
    $age[$i] = $birthdate->diff($now)->y;   
}

print_r($age);
```

Answer (score -1):

[Quick-test](https://eval.in/668522)

```
    <?php

        $day        = array(30, 03);
        $month      = array(07, 12);
        $year       = array(1998, 1997);
        $arrAges    = array();
        $todayTime  = new DateTime();

        foreach($year as $ikey=>$y){
            $birthDate      = $y . '-' .  $month[$ikey] . '-' . $day[$ikey];
            $bdTime         = new DateTime($birthDate);
            $ageInterval    = $todayTime->diff($bdTime);
            $arrAges[]      = $ageInterval->y;
        }

        var_dump($arrAges);
```

Comment: You should put `$todayTime` outside of the loop, there's no need to create it on every iteration.